# How do I convert degrees to radians and vice versa in Godot?

Tags: godot

In a game I'm toying with in Godot engine I have angles given in degrees in some places and angles given in radians in other places. Sometimes I need to mix both angles (ie. add them).

What built-in function allows me to convert degrees to radians (and the other way around)?
Or is there none?

P.S. I realize that converting those is not rocket science and I could code something on my own, but Godot is already doing such conversions internally, so I would venture a guess that such function already exists.

Comment: I'm down-voting this question for not showing research effort. Even not knowing Godot, I was able to find the engine documentation, enter a search for the word "degrees," and find the methods Tyyppi_77 links below in seconds. Please take the time to do at least this level of investigation when faced with a game development problem.

Comment: @DMGregory I guess I couldn't find those, because I was searching for "radians" in the documentation.

Comment: [Here are the search results for radians](https://imgur.com/a/I87Gr), which also include the hit that Tyyppi_77 links.

Comment: @DMGregory Then I guess I missed it (happens). P.S. I think our two comments in the middle can be deleted now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking if "[product X offers feature Y](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2383/should-we-consider-does-product-x-have-feature-y-type-questions-as-on-topic)".

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt while I agree the question isn't high-quality, I don't think it's off topic for that reason. The question here is really "what method do I use to convert..." not just asking if the conversion is a supported feature.

Comment: @DMGregory I really read it like "Does Godot have a feature (a function) that converts degrees to radians and vice versa?". It could be reworded, though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be achieved:

- Godot 3.x: using the [`deg2rad()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.6/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-deg2rad) and [`rad2deg`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.6/classes/class_@gdscript.html#class-gdscript-method-rad2deg) functions.
- Godot 4.x: using the [`deg_to_rad()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@globalscope.html#class-globalscope-method-deg-to-rad) and [`rad_to_deg()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@globalscope.html#class-globalscope-method-rad-to-deg) functions.

Each function takes a float (the value being converted) and returns a float (the converted value).

Answer (score 0):

Some nodes in Godot 3.0 have a property `rotation_degrees` that you can use, i.e

```
# rotate the node a quarter turn using radians
my_2D_node.rotation += PI / 2
# read the current rotation in degrees
my_2D_node.rotation_degrees
```

The property rotation_degrees can be read and set, so you can for example  write the property as `.rotation` in radians where convenient and somewhere else in the script read the property as `.rotation_degrees` if degrees would be more convenient.
The object will do the conversion for you

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: You're not answering the question. The OP is asking the way to convert `degree` to `radians` and vice versa.

Comment: Arguably, this could be an answer in some contexts. If the reason you wanted to convert between degrees & radians was that all your math was in degrees, but the nodes only had a rotation_radians property, then learning about a rotation_degrees property could solve the problem by letting you skip the conversion entirely. I would recommend editing this answer to explain how to use this property to solve the problem, or converting it to a comment as suggested above.

Comment: I also thought this was an answer as I had the same question as the OP and found this to be my solution. I'll clarify how it could be used